# Filling Infopath 2003 form programmatically using VB6

Tags: vb6, infopath

Is there a way to fill an Infopath 2003 form programmatically using Visual Basic 6 (for example through the COM interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infopath is XML based so there are no programming hooks (like you are thinking of) to manipulate the interface. It is possible to prefill a form from another language by manually changing the XML before the user opens it. InfoPath also supports multiple internal scripting languages if you are the form designer.

If you want to share more information about your situation we can recommend the best way.